# OpenGL goes green on tablets

Tags: android, opengl-es, tablet

Description:
My OpenGL game runs fine on phones. However, after a couple of seconds of running on a tablet the 3D rendering goes all green. The 2D overlays (gl) are mostly fine.
This might be triggered by rotation, I can't be sure; no access to a tablet.

A user kindly recording it happening, which I have posted online:
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DRfDM673TRA

Questions:
Has anyone seen this before, or know of a possible cause/cure?
Also, can anyone confirm this is is still happening? (BB Rally Lite is free).

Other info:
The game is locked into landscape mode so I wouldn't expect it to do anything on rotation.

**Update:**
This was a bug in my code.
Tablets have a different default orientation,
which was triggering conditional (bugged) code that never got run on a phone.

The green screen was a result of the bug causing the model's matrix to contain *nan* (or *inf*, I can't recall).

If you suffer from a green screen I suggest you start by looking at your matrices.

Comment: Incompatible openGL libraries on the device, I had that happen to a computer of mine where the graphics card 3D library was one version less than the game needed and the 2D stuff worked fine but the 3D rendering was non-existent.

Comment: When reading the question title I immediately thought *"So, they made OpenGL more resource friendly on tablets?"*, but then I realized you really meant *green* ;)